# Deploy build folder from Preact app to shared hosting

Tags: preact, preact-cli

I have an app built in Preact, and loaded the `/build` folder contents to my shared hosting space. When I went to that space from my domain name, nothing loaded. Is there an issue loading Preact and SSR apps vs how React generates files from an application?

How can I get my Preact app to render correctly on shared hosting?

Comment: `preact-cli` just creates static output, you can toss it up on any file server. Just make sure you're serving the right directory? Is your `index.html` 404'ing or what?

Comment: React and Preact are just UI libraries, not build tools. They do not generate files. There's many ways to create React apps, and they all create different output, so I don't know what you're referring to.

Comment: After doing some reading, realized I needed to create a .htaccess file for my sub folder. Main page is loading but js files loaded from react dom router aren’t rendering